# web3 can't connect to metamask (testnet)

Tags: web3js, metamask

i'm trying to connect my webiste to testnet using web3 but when i unlock metamask and connect metamask to testnet. web3 cannot connect to metamask.

please help me to solve this problem.

this is my code web3.

```
    web3 = require('web3');

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {

     web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
     console.log("existing web3: provider " + typeof web3);
  }
  else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/access_token"));
        console.log("new provider " + web3);
    }
```

Error : Provider not set or invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have wrong one line

```
Web3 = require('web3'); // <----  Here you need 'Web3' with 'W'

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    console.log("existing web3: provider " + typeof web3);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/access_token"));
    console.log("new provider " + web3);
}
```